# Relation 1-1 in hibernate not working : unknown column account0_.date_of_birth

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

I would like to create 1-1 relation in hiberante but I receive an error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'account0_.date_of_birth' in 'field list'
```

User table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
data class User(
        @NonNull
        @Column(nullable = false)
        var login: String,
        @NonNull
        @Column(nullable = false)
        var password: String,
        @NonNull
        @Column(nullable = false)
        var email: String
) {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int? = 0

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    @Nullable
    var bloodPressureInformationList: Set<BloodPressureInformation> = HashSet<BloodPressureInformation>()

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    var account: Account? = null

    constructor() : this("", "", "")
}
```

account table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
data class Account(
        @Column(nullable = false)
        @NonNull
        var firstName: String,
        @Column(nullable = false)
        @NonNull
        var lastName: String,
        @Column(nullable = false)
        @NonNull
        var dateOfBirth: String,
        @Column(nullable = false)
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @NonNull
        var sex: Sex) {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int? = 0

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    var user: User? = User()
}
```

Sql migration code:

```
Create Table user (
id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
login varchar(50),
password varchar (50),
email varchar(50),
CONSTRAINT user_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

Create Table blood_pressure (
id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
systolic_pulse INTEGER NOT NULL,
diastolic_pulse INTEGER NOT NULL,
pulse INTEGER,
description varchar(250),
CONSTRAINT blood_pressure_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE blood_pressure ADD COLUMN user_id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;
Create Table account (
id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
firstName varchar(50),
lastName varchar(50),
dateOfBirth varchar(50),
sex varchar(10),
CONSTRAINT account_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
ALTER TABLE user ADD COLUMN account_id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;
```

Could you tell me how to fix this relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your typo: `dateOfBirth varchar(50)` should be `date_of_birth varchar(50)`. Same goes for the other camel case columns.